# Load javascript file more than once doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm trying to load content from html pages in my index page depends on menu clicks. every html page (component) contains it's less file and it's js file. Now when I click on menu item it loads and runs both less & js files perfectly in the first time but in the 2nd time it only loads the files but doesn't run them.

how html page (component) looks like:

```
<link rel="stylesheet/less" href="/path/to/styles.less">
<div id="print_items">
  <h1>Print items</h1>
</div>
<script type="module" src="/path/to/script.js"></script>
```

I'm using this line to load the html page above inside index.php

```
$('#main_content').load('/path/to/html/page');
```

Now when I write the script inside HTML like this it works:

```
<link rel="stylesheet/less" href="/path/to/styles.less">
<div id="print_items">

</div>
<script >
  console.log('print items has been loaded');
</script>
```

Comment: My guess it has to do the fact you would have duplicate ids. But it is hard to tell do to the fact we see no code.

Comment: I understand loading again the files, will create the methods again and then, If they were executed, the methods will not be executed until being called specifically, could be? - as @epascarello also points, duplicated names, will create a collution and then fail

Comment: if you have eventlistenes on your event make sure to use `$.on('event', function(){})` instead of (eg) `$.click()`. otherwise the eventslisteners wont get attached to dynamically added elements

Comment: @AnzorAsadov I would think of that but the files gits loaded they just don't run.

Answer (score 0):

don't load script tag dynamically instead use single js file and make function to invoke by making click event

**single js file**

app.js

```
let print=()=>{
console.log('print') //do your stuff each function by clicking

}

let categiries=()=>{

console.log('category') //do your stuff each function by clicking
}
```

Tips:script dynamically loading not a good idea or load all script  at once make a function for each click event.